# Match concatenated columns from this worksheet to another worksheet with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets.  One is Sheet1 and another is Sheet2.
In Sheet2, I want to use a formula to get the value from column N in Sheet 1. 
I concatenate column A:B:C or A:B:D or A:B:E in Sheet1 and if any of this three conditions match X&Y&Z in sheet2, I get the value from column N in Sheet 1. 
The formula below seems make sense to me but I get #Value! error.

=INDEX(SHEET1!$N$2:$N$100,MATCH(X2&Y2&Z2,OR((SHEET1!$A$2:$A$100&SHEET1!$B$2:$B$100&SHEET1!$C$2:$C$100),(SHEET1!$A$2:$A$100&SHEET1!$B$2:$B$100&SHEET1!$D$2:$D$100), (SHEET1!$A$2:$A$100&SHEET1!$B$2:$B$100&SHEET1!$E$2:$E$100)),0))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting a new ColumnA into Sheet1 populated from A2 down to suit with:

```
=B2&C2&D2&E2&F2
```

then in Sheet2 applying:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$O$2:$O$100,MATCH(X2&Y2&Z2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,0))
```

This assumes your existing C, D and E columns in Sheet1 are blank if not containing the value you seek.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case because I need to find the combination of either ABC or ABD or ABE in sheet 1 to match XYX in sheet 2.  Any other suggestion?